# My React project deployed in GitHub Pages displays my NotFound component always

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I've already followed the simple and correct steps on how to deploy my React project in GitHub Pages, such as this one: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

Unfortunately, I don't know why my site is not working. It always displays my NotFound.js component, without any errors in the console. The deployed site is: https://krizferre.github.io/fewd-techdegree-project-11/

Here is a code snippet from my project:

```
class App extends Component {

    // All routes re-use one component which is Container, just depends on the keyword/category being searched
    // Home path '/' is redirected to '/cats' to initially have photos to display
    render() {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={ () => <Redirect to='/cats' /> } />
            <Route exact path="/search" render={ () => <Redirect to='/search/panda' /> } />
            <Route exact path="/search/:keyword" render={ props => <Container 
                                                                title='Results for ' 
                                                                keyword={props.match.params.keyword} 
                                                              />
                                                  } 
            />
            <Route exact path="/cats" render={ () => <Container title='Cat Gifs' keyword='cats' />} />
            <Route exact path="/dogs" render={ () => <Container title='Dog Gifs' keyword='dogs'/>} />
            <Route exact path="/birds" render={ () => <Container title='Bird Gifs' keyword='birds' />} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
}
```

All of my project codes are in https://github.com/krizferre/fewd-techdegree-project-11/tree/gh-pages.

Thank you

Comment: Have you used Create React App for this project? It seems looking by documentation. So might be this problem? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Yup, I used "create-react-app". I'll try the second solution of gaearon from the link you provided. I don't get his first solution though..